# How to make Maven find sibling modules, when run mvn in the sub-module directory?

Tags: maven

For example, I have a game project:

```
superegg/
  |- game/
  |   `- pom.xml -> (a lot of jars.)
  |- ai/
  |   `- pom.xml
  |- sprite/
  |   |- egg/
  |   |   `- pom.xml -> sprite
  |   |- badguy/
  |   |   `- pom.xml -> sprite, ai
  |   `- pom.xml -> game
  ` pom.xml
```

(Here `-->` means *depend on*)

All sub-modules are in SNAPSHOT versions, and they are not installed, neither deployed.

Now, I want to do something within `badguy/`:

```
.../sprite/badguy/ $ mvn exec:java ...
```

however, maven tries to find the dependencies `sprite, ai` from maven repositories, instead of `../../game` and `../../ai`.

How to make Maven resolve sub-module dependencies with-in the project dir?

I don't install them because there are too many submodules (though not listed here), a fully compile/install procedure takes a very long time). I've also tried but not succeeded:

```
superegg/sprite/badguy/ $ mvn --reactor dependency:build-classpath
    [INFO] Cannot execute mojo: build-classpath. It requires a project with an existing pom.xml, but the build is not using one.

superegg/ $ mvn -pl sprite/badguy dependency:build-classpath
    Missing dependencies: ...

superegg/ $ mvn --reactor -pl sprite/badguy dependency:build-classpath
    Project 'some-module' is duplicated in the reactor
```

BTW, I can build the whole project from superegg/ with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of my understanding, you cannot do that in Maven (it is a build tool, not an IDE). I suggest you do one of the following:

1. Use the maven-compiler-plugin in version 3.1. It ships with an incremental compiler that will skip compilation if nothing happened. This will speed up your work a great deal.
2. Build only those modules that you worked in by using the -pl option.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html
http://java.dzone.com/articles/5-maven-tips

I further recommend some sort of remote desktop or a ssh tunnel so that you can use Eclipse/IntelliJ/NetBeans. They provide just what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you load your top level pom from within IntelliJ, it will continually 'install' all the modules for you. I.e. it works out that you have a snapshot dependency which is already within the Maven reactor, so it doesn't bother going to your local repository.

Comment: IntelliJ is great, but I can't run it in ssh/telnet.